# APNS Notification from C#

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

One of my recent project i want to implement APNS Push Notification. So for that I want to send a Notification message to 100 iOS device at a time. So for that implementation i use a free JDSOFT library and also i refer following link.
http://apns-sharp.googlecode.com/svn-history/r21/trunk/JdSoft.Apple.Apns.Notifications.Test/Program.cs

Here my problem is when i send a message to a particular device i want to wait for a little amount time before sending next notification. for that i use

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);

Otherwise some of my message successfully received and some of then failed to receive.
But If I use 15000 m.seconds then my thread wait upto 15000*100 millisecond.

So is there any way to avoid such problem. Or If anyone know what is the minimum sleep time between the notification. I am using C# for notification implementation. If anyone know, please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the author of APNS-Sharp, and I'd recommend checking out PushSharp instead (which I also wrote).  It supercedes APNS-Sharp and should not have the problem you are experiencing!

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp